# Is my probability correct

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, fractions

> Suppose you draw $1$ athlete at random from a group of $100$ athletes such that:
>
> $\{$$30$ swim$\}$, $\{$$44$ run$\}$, $\{$$9$ swim and run$\}$,$\{$$5$ swim, bike and run$\}$, $\{$$11$ swim and bike$\}$, $\{$$10$ bike and run but do not swim$\}$, and
> $\{$$35$ only bike$\}$.

Let $S, B,$ and $R$ denote the events that the athlete you draw $\text{Swims}$, $\text{Bikes}$, and $\text{Runs}$,
respectively. I give the following probabilities:
$$P (S \cup R) = \frac{55}{100} + \frac{68}{100} - \frac{9}{100} = \frac{114}{100} $$
$$P (S \cup B) = \frac{55}{100} + \frac{61}{100} - \frac{11}{100} = \frac{105}{100}$$
Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Where did the $55$ come from in your attempt?  Should that not simply have been $30$ in its place?  Similarly for the $68$ that follows...  The information as given should be interpreted "30 swim (*and possibly participate in additional activities*)" and can be read as $\Pr(S)=\dfrac{30}{100}$

Comment: Both answers start with the essential rule ; No probability can be greater than $1$. In an exam, you can make errors, you can ignore some rules, no problem, but if you write : Proba = 1.14, the exam will stop immediatly.

Answer (score 2):

No probability can be greater than $1$.

I think, for instance, the $5$ who swim and run are also included among the $30$ who swim, and the $44$ who run.

Answer (score 0):

Probabilities can't be greater than 1.
Your approach didn't consider that for example the $5$ who swim and run are also included among the $30$ who swim, and the $44$ who run.

For $P(S \cup R)$:
$$
P(S \cup R) = P(S) + P(R) - P(S \cap R) = \frac{30}{100} + \frac{44}{100} - \frac{9}{100} = \frac{65}{100}
$$

For $P(S \cup B)$:
$$
P(S \cup B) = P(S) + P(B) - P(S \cap B) = \frac{30}{100} + \left( \frac{35 + 10 + 6 + 5}{100} \right) - \left( \frac{6 + 5}{100} \right) = \frac{75}{100}
$$
Venn Diagram:
[image]